# error pushing flask application in heroku: sqlite3 missing

Tags: python, heroku, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to push a Flask application into Heroku. But if i start the application, it crashes giving the following error:

```
2012-06-13T18:30:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
2012-06-13T18:30:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
2012-06-13T18:30:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     from _sqlite3 import *
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure Heroku supports SQLite. I would use PostgreSQL for production websites.

You can follow the Django tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) to figure out how to setup PostgreSQL.